# TForm: Add a message handler and call inherited

Tags: c++builder

Let´s say I need to create a Windows message handler in my C++ Builder cpp file.

I'll write a handler for `WM_SIZE` like this:

h file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, TWMSize, OnWMSize)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TControl)

void __fastcall OnWMSize(TWMSize &msg);
```

cpp file:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::OnWMSize(TWMSize &msg)
{
    if (msg.SizeType == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)
        Caption = "Maximized";

    // This is a Delphi call and won't work in C++:
    // inherited;

    // Cpp call. Won't compile due to method visibility (private)
    // TForm::WMSize(msg);

    // Cpp call. Compiles but doesn't get expected behavior
    DefaultHandler((void*)&msg);
}
```

As shown in the example, using Delphi this is pretty straightforward, just call `inherited`.

But using C++, how do I call the base class in C++ Builder? `WMSize` method is declared as private in `TScrollingWinControl`.

In this example, not calling the base class breaks `Anchors` functionality. Using `DefaultHandler` won't solve the problem, either.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you are passing the wrong class type to `END_MESSAGE_MAP()`.  You need to specify the *immediate parent class*, which in this case is `TForm`, not `TControl`:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, TWMSize, OnWMSize)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm) // <-- here
```

Now, that being said, a `MESSAGE_MAP` is just a fancy way of overriding the virtual `Dispatch()` method:

```
#define BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP   virtual void __fastcall Dispatch(void *Message) \
        {                                           \
          switch  (((PMessage)Message)->Msg)        \
          {

#define VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(msg,type,meth)          \
          case    msg:                              \
            meth(*((type *)Message));               \
            break;

// NOTE: ATL defines a MESSAGE_HANDLER macro which conflicts with VCL's macro. The
//       VCL macro has been renamed to VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER. If you are not using ATL,
//       MESSAGE_HANDLER is defined as in previous versions of BCB.
//
#if !defined(USING_ATL) && !defined(USING_ATLVCL) && !defined(INC_ATL_HEADERS)
#define MESSAGE_HANDLER  VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER
#endif // ATL_COMPAT

#define END_MESSAGE_MAP(base)           default:    \
                        base::Dispatch(Message);    \
                        break;                      \
          }                                         \
        }
```

So, your `MESSAGE_MAP` resolves to the following code logic:

```
virtual void __fastcall Dispatch(void *Message)
{
  switch  (((PMessage)Message)->Msg)
  {
    case WM_SIZE:
      OnWMSize(*((TWMSize *)Message));
      break;
    default:
      TForm::Dispatch(Message);
      break;
  }
}
```

As you can see, `END_MESSAGE_MAP()` simply passes unhandled messages to the base class `TForm::Dispatch()` method.  You must do the same in your message handlers, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::OnWMSize(TWMSize &msg)
{
    if (msg.SizeType == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)
        Caption = "Maximized";

    TForm::Dispatch(&msg);
}
```